# C# Forms - Only the first of what should be two consecutive events triggers

Tags: c#, events

I have a TextBox with a "Leave" event and a Button with a "Click" event.  There is no code in either event handler.

1. If I place the cursor in the TextBox then leave it by clicking any other item, the "Leave" event triggers.
2. If I place the cursor anywhere except in the TextBox and click the Button, the "Click" event triggers.
3. However, if I click the Button with the cursor inside the TextBox, only the "Leave" event triggers.

How can I get both events to trigger in the third scenario?

Comment: How can click Button when cursor is inside other control? Could you share the code and add UI to visualise the problem?

Comment: Typically this means that you are doing something in the `Leave` event that is blocking the `Click` event, like showing a `MessageBox`. Can you please share your code so that we can see what is going on?

Comment: The `Leave` event will break the event chain, that's why the `Click` event isn't being called. In all honesty it does work, remove breakpoints and throw a `Console.WriteLine` in both events, then watch the output. If breakpoints are on there and or something else that would block the other event, you wont see it being called.

Comment: @Michal  To answer your question: 1. Place the mouse pointer over the TextBox and left-click to place the cursor in the TextBox.  2.  Place the mouse pointer over the Button and left-click to click the Button.

Comment: @Codexer - It was definitely a misunderstanding on my part and it does work properly as you indicated.  I had a breakpoint in the Leave handler just to make sure it occurred and I didn't realize that breakpoints apparently break the event chain :-(